# NullReferenceException thrown on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm having a problem with intermittent exceptions thrown on a multithreaded program.
These exceptions came from a call to OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar.
The query used is a count(*), so it's not possible to return null.

That is the C# code calling the ExecuteScalar.

```
    public bool HasCodUniorgLinkedToREP(long numIdRep)
    {
        string strQuery = "select count(*) from tbl_uniorgrep where num_idrep = :p_num_idrep";

        using (OracleCommand oraCmdUniorg = OraLib.CreateCommand(strQuery, oraConn))
        {
            oraCmdUniorg.Parameters.Add("p_num_idrep", OracleDbType.Decimal, numIdRep, ParameterDirection.Input);

            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(oraCmdUniorg.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception e = new Exception("Error Message.", ex);
                e.Data.Add("REP ID", numIdRep);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception thrown from this code is the following:

```
Exception Info:
Type: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
Stack Trace:
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExtractAccessorValuesIntoParam(OracleParameterCollection paramColl, OracleConnection connection, Int32 paramCount, String commandText, Int64 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, Int64 internalInitialLOBFS, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bCallFromExecuteReader)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at FassiLib.REPCollector.DB.REP.HasCodUniorgLinkedToREP(Int64 numIdRep)
```

Does anyone have a clue why is this exception been thrown?

Sometimes it is thrown by more than a thread during the execution. Other times by only one of the threads.
Most of the executions the exception is not thrown at all.

The program has a batch behavior and creates about 70 threads per execution.

TIA

Comment: does your connection object oraConn exists, is it instantiated and is opened?

Comment: I've been through a similar problem once. Instance methods of OracleCommand do not guarantee thread safety. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/OracleCommandClass.htm#ODPNT458

Comment: yes. it's a class variable and is created/instantiated/opened on the class constructor.

Comment: @EdgarRochaCarvalho, very interesting. i'll test with static methods.

Comment: ooops... forget my last comment. there is no static version of ExecuteScalar. i'll rewrite using OracleDataAdapter/DataSet.